# Prove that the polynomial divided by a fraction of the power of n is equal to the sum of fractions of any constans and successive powers of

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

Let n≥1 and n is integer. P(x) - polynomial and $deg P(x)<n$. Prove if $ a \in \Bbb R/{0} $  then:

$ \frac{P(x)}{(ax+b)^n} = \frac{c_1}{ax+b} + \frac{c_2}{(ax+b)^2}+...+\frac{c_n}{(ax+b)^n}$ 
  for appropriately selected constants $ c_1, c_2, ... c_n$.

So let's write P(x) as Taylor series. 
$ P(x) = f(t) + f'(t) \frac{x-t}{1} + ... + f^{(k)}\frac{(x-t)^k}{k!} + R_k$ and $k<n$ 
I need to find a good t. 
$ax+b = x-t$ ? I don't know what is next.

Comment: This is one of the most basic and important theorems, in particular within integration theory.

Comment: +1 Your idea seems to be good, @keri: why don't you try to develop $\,p(x)\,$ around $\,-\frac ba\;$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: Taylor polynomial around $\,\alpha:=-\frac ba\;$ :

$$P(x)=P(\alpha)+\frac{P'(\alpha)(x-\alpha)}{1!}+\frac{P''(\alpha)(x-\alpha)}{2!}+\ldots\implies$$

Please observe that $\,x-\alpha=x+\frac ba\;$:

$$\frac{P(x)}{(ax+b)^n}=\frac1{a^n}\frac{P(x)}{\left(x+\frac ba\right)^n}=\ldots$$

Comment: Ok, I see. But what should I do with $R_k$ ?

Comment: If I understand your notation,. $\,R_k\,$ is just the remainder of order $\;k\;$, and this is zero once $\,k=\deg f\,$ ...:)

Comment: but it is possible k+2<n so then I have to count remainder.